# Zxing's barcode scanner is not able to scan the barcode, is there any other option

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I need to develop an Android app which would scan a barcode that is alphanumeric, i have installed the barcode scanner app from Zxing, but it is not able to scan this type of barcode. I have integrated the same to my android app, is there any way I could resolve this?

Comment: Can you post an image of the barcode?

Comment: What format does your barcode has?
Maybe you can try another barcodescanner like http://www.scandit.com/barcode-scanner-sdk/video/android/

Comment: I have tried scanning this barcode using the scanner, it was not able to read it... http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://pimg.tradeindia.com/00161927/b/0/Alpha-Numeric-Barcodes.jpg&imgrefurl=http://multiforms.tradeindia.com/alpha-numeric-barcodes-161927.html&h=225&w=300&sz=11&tbnid=uMFbLwyFZiuIQM:&tbnh=90&tbnw=120&zoom=1&usg=__ZUEdWtTBXwPv4iDzeH2YT-UyNZw=&docid=mUEdkSwfeYrQRM&sa=X&ei=HRyRUfXzH4f88QSewoHICA&ved=0CDsQ9QEwAQ&dur=120

Comment: According to ZXing's Online decoder the image you linked it can be decoded: http://zxing.org/w/decode?u=http%3A%2F%2Fpimg.tradeindia.com%2F00161927%2Fb%2F0%2FAlpha-Numeric-Barcodes.jpg, is this the same bar code you are trying to scan or just an example of the kind of code you are trying to scan?

Comment: It was an example of what I was trying to decode. But, I was not able to decode the same from the app installed on my android phone.

Comment: I'm just trying to isolate where the problem might be occurring.  If we know the bar code is valid and we know ZXing can handle it, then what about this app, is there an example of a bar code that it can scan?

Comment: The barcode that I was trying to scan was of the format EAN_8. Was able to decode using the above link. The app was able to decode most of the barcodes that represented only numeric data, for example http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&gl=IN&ie=UTF-8&source=android-browser&q=barcode+image&redir_esc=&ei=mUGRUZPCBNDorQessIGoCA#biv=i%7C0%3Bd%7CM5V7J_u2RcL3xM%3A

Answer (score 1):

That is a Code 39 barcode, or is trying to be. It looks slightly corrupted by image resizing; the bars are stretched to the wrong widths.

EDIT: no, it's actually insufficient quiet zone / white space -- see comment. But I don't know what the real required minimum is, anyone?

I also sent it to http://www.onlinebarcodereader.com/ and it did not decode. But it did at http://www.online-barcode-decoder.com/

Ideally you use a better source barcode, since this is rejected by the heuristics in zxing. You could modify the code to be more lenient, although at some point it will create false positives.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what do you mean by modifying the code to be more lenient.

Comment: I put this through the debugger, and actually the problem is a little different. The decoder looks for some white space before the start of the barcode, like in most barcodes. It is looking for half the width of the guard pattern, but there's not enough white space before and after. If you remove that check it succeeds. The problem with removing it is potentially matching false positives. Does anyone have a reference that says how much white space belongs at the start and end? maybe this rule is too strict. The decoding itself works fine

Comment: Ah, found this: http://www.acordex.com/consulting/BarCode39.html  Looks like the answer is that white space needs to be at least 10 narrow bars. EDIT: the guard pattern is 6 narrow and 3 wide bars, where a wide bar is about 2.5x narrow. The total width is 13.5x narrow. So this reference suggests that much more than half the guard pattern width is required; the code is actually too lenient! in any event, the image itself has well too little whitespace before and after and that's the issue.